# AttributeError: 'Reddit' object has no attribute 'set_oauth_app_info'

Tags: python, reddit, attributeerror, praw

So I created a reddit module for my IRC Bot in windows, using PRAW. It worked fine. When I changed it over to my linux machine, it worked fine as well - until I tried to get the bot to login. It is erroring out at this:

```
user_agent = ('blahblahblah')
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
r.set_oauth_app_info(client_id='IDREMOVED',
            client_secret='SECRETREMOVED',
            redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:65010/'
                'authorize_callback')
r.login('USERNAMEREMOVED', 'PASSWORDREMOVED')
```

and I get,

> AttributeError: 'Reddit' object has no attribute '`set_oauth_app_info`'

This is a fresh install of PRAW so I don't know what could be causing this issue. The same code works great on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same version of PRAW? Sometimes, the versions you get on linux depending on how you installed it are different than what you expect..

Comment: @sihrc That did it. I can't believe it was that simple. Apparently yum got a different version that pip did. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, these things happen with package managers. It's happened to me far too many times :(. Usually you'd need to specify the version or update the refs.